# How to view the contents of a TADODataSet instance during debugging?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

How to view the contents of a TADODataSet instance during debugging? There are no properties or anything useful visible in the watch window. In .NET, there's the dataset visualiser which shows the data in a grid. Anything similar in Delphi?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you can't.

The Delphi IDE is just not like that. This is a question I asked as a Visual studio user first encountering Delphi.

They designed it to allow third parties to write [debugging visualizers](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/40268), but I have never seen one for datasets.

Comment: sure you can, using a TDataSource and a TDBgrid you can see the contents at design time ;)